# Can we always fail an ajax request from browser / frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, drupal-7

I have a form in Drupal 7, I am using ajax to submit the form, how can I fail the ajax request from frontend i.e. ui, I always want to show 500 internal server error when I submit the form. How can I do this ?

Comment: Why would you fail it from the front end?

Comment: What scenario do you want to do this? Are you trying to do it for a unit test or something (only reason I can think of normally)?

Comment: Just want to recreate a scenario so as to implement security measures on site

Comment: change the ajax request url to a random url, it will always redirect to page_not_found and you will get error, or you can disable javascript in your browser